How to match video duration with music's duration?
I have a video file and music files, I want to match the video duration with multiple musics in min diff = ideo duration, sum of musics duraion. I use code as below, but it  looks like not all answers, what can I get all combination? do I have to use recursion？
musicList = [music filename list
timeList = [music file duraion list]]
tList = []
mList = []
dList = []

for i, (m1, t1) in enumerate(zip(musicList, timeList)):
    if t1 > videoTime:
        continue

    time1 = t1
    music1 = m1

    for j in range(i + 1, len(musicList) - 1):
        time2 = time1
        music2 = music1

        for m2, t2 in zip(musicList[j:], timeList[j:]):
            if t2 > videoTime or time2 + t2 > videoTime:
                continue

            time = max(time2, t2, time2 + t2)
            music2 = music2 if time == time2 else m2 if time == t2 else f'{music2}+{m2}'
            time2 = time

        mList.append(music2)
        tList.append(time2)
        dList.append(videoTime - time2)


some example input and output

You can use itertools.combinations() to try and find suitable combinations of music tracks.
